# HTML5 - Converting Dynamic Text to Path

Tags: html, animation, text, vector

So I'm wondering if there is a way to convert a string with a given font face to a set of coordinates and have these coordinates accessible to align other elements to - specifically images, though any DOM element ideally.

Basically I want to be able to animate a set of elements and have them form the given string, but its the first step I need to get through at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What specifically are you trying to do? Align other elements to the top of a specific character? Move the text around? Move it character by character? What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: _MAYBE you can do it with svg fonts_ ? but, most probably, - there is not way to do that in html.

Answer (score 0):

I you display the string on the page in a given element, *e.g.*, in a span or div, then you can get the coordinates of the upper, left corner of that element and you can get the width and height of that element. Assuming you have set your CSS attributes appropriately, this will give you something very close to the coordinates of the text, perhaps event exact.

If you don't want to display the string, you could set its opacity to 0.01.